# connecting Neo4j to nodejs error

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to set up neo4j databace to use with javescript code.
When I run my code, I keep getting this

> PS C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j> node app.js body-parser
>   deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option app.js:21:20
>   Server has started GET / 304 37.114 ms - - { Neo4jError: getaddrinfo
>   ENOTFOUND locthost locthost:7687
>
> ```
>     at captureStacktrace (C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\result.js:200:15)
>     at new Result (C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\result.js:73:19)
>     at Session._run (C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\session.js:122:14)
>     at Session.run (C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\v1\session.js:101:19)
>     at C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\app.js:31:4
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>     at next (C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>     at C:\Users\futur\Documents\Coding\Neo4j\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> ```
>
> code: 'ServiceUnavailable', name: 'Neo4jError' }

Here is what my code looks like

```
var express         = require("express");
var path            = require("path");
var logger          = require("morgan");
// var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var bodyParser      = require("body-parser");
var neo4j           = require("neo4j-driver").v1;

var app             = express();


// 
// <script src="lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js"></script>


//view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extened: false}));
// app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://locthost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "test"));
var session = driver.session();

//home route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    session 
        .run("MATCH (n) RETURN n")
        .then(function(result){
            result.records.forEach(function(records){
                console.log(records._fields[0]);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    res.render("index");
});


app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server has started');

module.export = app;
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

You may have a typo in your `bolt` URI.

If your code is running on the same machine as the neo4j server, try changing `locthost` to `localhost`.